# Handling a very big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

Right now I'm having trouble on how to process my data and transform it into a dataframe. Basically what I'm trying to do is to read the data first

```
data = pd.read_csv(querylog, sep=" ", header=None)
```

then group it

```
query_group = data.groupby('Query')
ip_group = data.groupby('IP')
```

and lastly create a blank dataframe to map their values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=query_group.groups, index=range(0, len(ip_group.groups)))

index = 0
for name, group in ip_group:
    df.set_value(index, 'IP', name)
    index += 1
df = df.set_index('IP')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    df.set_value(row['IP'], row['Query'], 1)
    print(index)
df = df.fillna(0)
```

So my problem is that the **ip_group can go up to a size of 6000** and **query_group up to 400000** which would result in making a very big blank dataframe that my memory cannot handle. Can anyone help me on how to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Sample dataframe of the data would look like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame( { "Query" : ["google.com", "youtube.com", "facebook.com"],
     "IP" : ["192.168.0.104", "192.168.0.103","192.168.0.104"] } )
```

and my expected output would look like this

```
                google.com youtube.com  facebook.com
IP            
192.168.0.104   1          0             1
192.168.0.103   0          1             0
```

Comment: is there a special reason you are filling you DF in loops using df.set_value() instead of working with data sets/panels/series ?

Comment: Can you add sample of dataframe `data` ?

Comment: @MaxU it is my first solution I could think of since get_dummies would result in memory error too. Any solution you could provide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but without data is problematic find the best solution:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(data.set_index('IP')['Query'])
print df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame( { "Query" : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a" , "b"],
     "IP" : [1,5,4,8,3,4] } )
print data  
   IP Query
0   1     a
1   5     b
2   4     c
3   8     d
4   3     a
5   4     b
```

```
#set index from column data
data = data.set_index('IP')

#get dummies from column Query
df = pd.get_dummies(data['Query'])
print df
    a  b  c  d
IP            
1   1  0  0  0
5   0  1  0  0
4   0  0  1  0
8   0  0  0  1
3   1  0  0  0
4   0  1  0  0

#groupby by index and sum columns
print df.groupby(df.index).sum()
    a  b  c  d
IP            
1   1  0  0  0
3   1  0  0  0
4   0  1  1  0
5   0  1  0  0
8   0  0  0  1
```

Try convert to `int8` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for savings 3 times less memory:

```
print pd.get_dummies(data['Query']).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 3 entries, 192.168.0.104 to 192.168.0.104
Data columns (total 3 columns):
facebook.com    3 non-null float64
google.com      3 non-null float64
youtube.com     3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes

print pd.get_dummies(data['Query']).astype(np.int8).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 3 entries, 192.168.0.104 to 192.168.0.104
Data columns (total 3 columns):
facebook.com    3 non-null int8
google.com      3 non-null int8
youtube.com     3 non-null int8
dtypes: int8(3)
memory usage: 33.0+ bytes

print pd.get_dummies(data['Query'], sparse=True).info()
<class 'pandas.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>
Index: 3 entries, 192.168.0.104 to 192.168.0.104
Data columns (total 3 columns):
facebook.com    3 non-null float64
google.com      3 non-null float64
youtube.com     3 non-null float64
```

Comment: I would like to set this as an answer but sadly this would just result in memory error because the number of query could go as much as 100000 and my ip data could go as much as 5000

Comment: I edit answer, but question is how much memory do you have in your PC.

Comment: Have you tried get_dummies(sparse=True)? This should give you a sparse array, which is more memory-efficient since your data is mostly zeros. (requires pandas version 0.16.1)

Comment: @Rob It is in `7.` row from the end of my answer.